# Is `git merge --squash` a merge operation indeed?

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is the [merge process with different parameters described in  graph](https://segmentfault.com/img/bVkJAj/view).(unable to directly insert the graph due to the format compatibility)

As we know,if we use `git merge --no-ff target` on `master` branch to merge `target branch` into `master`,then it will generate a new node with two predecessors,and we can see two branches printed using `git log`.

However ,if we use `git merge --squash`+`git commit`,then it will just generate a new node with one predecessor,and if we use `git log`,just the current branch is printed.

From my point of view,as a result of merge,the new node should have two predecessors(`--ff` is a special case).One is the `current branch`,another is the target branch that is merged from.So the although the `--squash` is a  merge operation literally,it's actually just a `commit` operation on current branch,am I right?

What's more,after the `--squash` operation,when I `checkout` to the `target branch`,the `commits` on that branch is not squashed actually.If I use `git log` on the `target branch`,the commit history are still there and not squashed.

Comment: A squash rewrites history, leaving you with a _new_ commit which is the result of one or more other commits which were combined.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No,the history of `target` branch is not squashed or rewote. Because after the squash I `checkout` to the other branch and use `git log`, the commits are still there and not combined actually.

Comment: I didn't say the history of the other branch gets affected; it doesn't.  You rewrote the history of the branch which got squashed.

Comment: Do you mean that it's the `master` branch that is squashed,not the `target` branch?But the picture shows it's the `target` branch that is squashed.Actually I did not see the history got changed after the `--squash`,just a new `commit` occurs .

Comment: Correct. `merge --squash` does not create a merge commit. It goes through the motions of a merge, but at the last second it creates a single-parent commit instead.

Comment: @RaymondChen So the `--squash` actually `squash` nothing and does not change the history of both branch ?

Comment: It adds a commit to the destination branch and makes no change to the source branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I like to describe this is that in Git, the word *merge* itself occurs in two forms.  One is the verb, *to merge*, which describes an action.  The other uses the word as an adjective, in the phrase *a merge commit*, or as a noun, in the phrase *a merge*, which is just a shortened form of *merge commit* (so it plays the same role whether it is used as adjective or noun).

#### Merge as a verb

The verb form of *to merge* describes a process in which Git:

- chooses a merge base: some particular commit<sup>1</sup> to use as the basis of the merge process;
- chooses two commits<sup>2</sup> we can designate *L* and *R*, for *left* and *right*, or *local* and *remote*, or `--ours` and `--theirs`;
- generates a (sometimes at least partly virtual) pair of `git diff` outputs: one compares the chosen base to *L*, and the other compares the chosen base to *R;*
- combines these diffs to produce a merged result, with the occasional failure due to a merge conflict.

On failure, the conflicts are stored in Git's *index*, using the stage numbering system: files stored in index stage slot 1 are files from the merge base, files in stage slot 2 are those from the *L* or `--ours` commit, and files in stage slot 3 are those from the *R* or `--theirs` commit.  On success, the merge result is *still* stored in Git's index, it's just that every file is in the more normal slot-zero entry.  If you use `git mergetool`, this extracts the conflicted files from these stage 1-3 entries.  The work-tree copies of the files are in many ways just a side effect: Git's commits are all built from the index, not from the work-tree.

Eventually—or right away if there is no failure and you did not say `--no-commit`—the result of this merge will probably be committed.  If there is a failure and there is a mess left in the index, you can abort out of whatever operation kicked off this merge-as-a-verb process.  If you did say `--no-commit` you can likewise abort instead of committing.  But usually, there will be a final commit.  That gets us to the other meaning of the word *merge*, in the next section (after these footnotes).

---

<sup>1</sup>A *recursive* merge handles the rare-ish case when there are multiple best-commit candidates, by merging the merge bases to make a new commit.  For all the cases we care about here, though, there is always one merge base.

<sup>2</sup>This ignores *octopus merges* but they do not quite fit into this model.  Octopus merges cannot use the index to stage multiple input files, and cannot deal with complicated conflicts.  (There's probably no fundamental reason they could not—one can imagine Git storing stages 1 through *N* for some large *N*—but they don't.)

---

#### Merge as an adjective or noun

This is much simpler: a *merge commit* is any commit with at least two parents.  Other than having more than one parent, a merge commit is the same as any other commit:  Each stores a complete snapshot, which Git made by turning the files in your index at the time you made the commit into one of these permanent read-only snapshots.  Again, the work-tree is just a sideshow, except in that it allows you to copy worked-on files *into* the index.  The index acts as a proposed, but writable, commit.  (Commits are entirely read-only: they cannot be changed, once made.)

#### Fast-forwards are not merges

Fast-forwarding is not a merge at all.  Instead, it's a property of a Git reference motion.  This is why `git push` and `git fetch` talk about fast-forwards or forced updates: `git push` proposes to make a change to some other Git's references, typically by changing branch name references (such as `refs/heads/master`) in a Git repository that your own Git calls `origin`.  Similarly, `git fetch` makes a change to remote-tracking names (such as `refs/remotes/origin/master`) in your own Git repository, based on the reference values seen in the Git repository that your own Git calls `origin`.

#### What `git merge` does

The `git merge` front-end command can do one or more of the things listed above:

- It *will* (in general) find a common ancestor to use as a merge base.
- If this common ancestor is a *different commit* from both *L* and *R*, a true merge is required.  If not prohibited via `--ff-only`, this `git merge` will do a merge-as-a-verb.
- If this common ancestor is *L* itself, then *L* ≼ *R*.  That is, *L* is an ancestor of *R*, or the two are the same commit.

  - If they are the same commit, there is nothing to do.
  - Otherwise a fast-forward is possible.  If not prohibited via `--no-ff`, this `git merge` will do a fast-forward operation on the current branch and check out commit *R* (to update the index and work-tree).  If fast-forward is prohibited, this `git merge` will perform a merge-as-a-verb.
- If the common ancestor is *R* itself, then we have *R* ≼ *L* (*R* is an ancestor of *L*).  There is nothing to do: either they are the same commit, or you're suggesting that Git move backwards, but it won't.  The merge command will do nothing.

At this point, if `git merge` did a fast-forward instead of a merge, everything is done and `git merge` simply exits (finishes up with an appropriate status).  If there was nothing to do or (via `--ff-only`) the thing to do was prohibited, `git merge` exits.  So only the merge-as-a-verb cases remain: `git merge` is now committed to performing the verb form of *to merge*.

In any case `git merge` will normally record something *about* this merge operation, namely that it has this extra commit *R* as an input.  This will make the eventual commit have two parents: it will be a *merge commit*.  If you use `--squash`, however, `git merge` deliberately *omits* this extra parent information.

If the verb form of *to merge* fails, `git merge` prints complaints and exits, but if it succeeds, `git merge` proceeds on to the last step, which is to run `git commit` to conclude the merge—unless, of course, you used `--no-commit` to tell it not to commit.  For no particularly good reason, `--squash` implies `--no-commit` always.

#### Conclusion

This gives us our answer to your question:

> Is `git merge --squash` a merge operation?

Assuming we take all the special cases out of the way—that we eliminate things like fast-forward merges, or complaints that there is nothing to merge—then the answer depends on whether you mean the verb form, *to merge*, or the adjective form, *a merge commit*.  With `--squash`, `git merge` *performs* the merge—it runs the merge machinery by finding a merge base and producing and combining the changesets—but it *makes* an ordinary, non-merge commit.  The answer is therefore both yes and no.